# How can i patch this unwanted and strange iteration in javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, iteration

I made this simple script for searching video on YouTube but, there is a strange echo of this code:

```
var nPageToken = response.nextPageToken;
if (nPageToken){
    $('#moreButton').css('display','block');
    $('#moreButton').click(function(){
        searchRequest('', nPageToken);
    });
} else {
    $('#moreButton').css('display','none');
}
```

that creates a strange effects when, clicking on "more result" on the bottom of the page for 4 or 5 times. 
This is the [complete code](http://searchtube.altervista.org/en/search.js), try the [home page](http://searchtube.altervista.org/en/index.html) and click four or five times on "more button" on the bottom and see the iteration of the `searchrequest` with the same `pageToken` I can not understand why, can you help me? thank you

Comment: Is that code inside the searchRequest function? That would explain it (every call to the function would add a new click handler).

Comment: Yes it is. Pardon my ignorance, what means, in simple terms? do i need to place it out of the searchRequest? By the way i did not catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you clarification in the comments, you can't call `$('#moreButton').click(...)` from inside the `searchRequest` function, since that's making another call to `searchRequest`. Here is what's going on:

1. `searchRequest` is called for the first time. If `nPageToken` is truthy (i.e., not null, undefined, false or 0), a click handler to `#moreButton` will be added, so that `searchRequest` is called when that button is clicked.
2. You click the button, and `searchRequest` is called. But if `if (nPageToken)` passes, you'll then be adding a second click handler, so the next click on the button will call `searchRequest` *twice*.
3. If you click the button again, the same thing will happen, and `searchRequest` will be called 4 times on the following click. And so on, growing exponentially...

The solution seems to be moving this part outside `searchRequest`:

```
$('#moreButton').click(function(){
    searchRequest('', nPageToken);
});
```

Comment: Thank you many time, now it works and i understand why too. what kind of a noob i'am?!

Comment: The good kind, because you actually wanted to understand the *why*! :) Glad to help you!